# python - run command on windows from linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, command, rename

I am trying to rename a remote Windows machine from a Linux machine.
How can I do that with administrator privileges?

My final function should look like:

```
run_windows_command('servername', 'powershell.exe rename-computer
-NewName NEWNAME', 'domain\username', 'password')
```

thank you

Comment: [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm)?

Comment: or [winexe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) ?

Comment: Already tried, but the commands are running without administrator privileges

Comment: even using [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.10).aspx) command ?

Comment: If it's joined to a domain you could use samba to do it: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/net.8.html#idp5170656

Comment: You could try `psexec` with option `-h`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: @n00dl3, runas.exe can't elevate in Vista+ w/ UAC. To use runas, you'd need to enable the "Administrator" account (RID 500), with a policy that excludes this account from UAC restrictions.